# how to open a new tab with session by clicking link button in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a link button inside repeater and i just want to open it in a new tab with session.
I have tried many things but it doesn't work well.

### HTML

```asp
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RP_UniversityInfo">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="boxes">
                <div class="boxes_img ImageWrapper">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Link_Uni_Image" 
                      CommandName="Link_Uni_Image" 
                      CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>' 
                      OnClick="Link_Uni_Image_Click">
                        <img class="img-responsive" 
                          src='<%# "upload/"+ Eval("image") %>' alt='<%#Eval("name") %>'>
                        <div class="PStyleNe"></div>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                    <div class="box_type"><%#Eval("con_name") %></div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="title">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Link_Uni" 
                      CommandName="Link_Uni" 
                      CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>' 
                      OnClick="Link_Uni_Click"> 
                        <%#Eval("name") %>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </h2>
            </div><!-- end boxes -->
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

### Code Behind

```
LinkButton LnkBtn = (LinkButton)sender;
RepeaterItem item = LnkBtn.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
University_Id = Convert.ToInt32(LnkBtn.CommandArgument);
Session["university"] = University_Id;
Response.Redirect("University_Details.aspx");
```

I tried JavaScript also but same result. It opens a new tab  but refreshes whole page and also opens new tab by clicking on Dropdownlist also.
Help me out!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `<asp:HyperLink>` that will open link in new tab.

```
<asp:HyperLink  NavigateUrl="http://websiteurl.com" Target="_blank" />
```

> Because the `LinkButton` control is used to create a hyperlink-style
>   button on the Web page. The `LinkButton` control has the same
>   appearance as a `HyperLink` control, but has the same functionality as
>   a Button control. If you want to link to another Web page when the
>   control is clicked, consider using the `HyperLink` control.

**Edit : If you can not change to HyperLink then follow below approach.**

Add [OnClientClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick.aspx) event.

```
OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"
```

So on click it will call `JavaScript` function and it will open respective link in new tab.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lnkLink" OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';" runat="Server" />
```

Comment: But there is no onclick event on hyperlink

Comment: But i have to pass session and in this session there is a ID which retrieve by clicking on linkbutton through command argument. how can i achieve this.

Comment: I tried this earlier but it doesn't work stays on same page